# Balcony time causing tension

Tags: cats

My cat, adopted about 9 months ago has started to get bored with my apartment, so I have been spending time sitting with him on the balcony for my smoke breaks while working from home or in the evenings. The problem has now started to emerge where he would get extremely upset every time we have to go back inside, swiping at me etc. How can I reduce tension or create a routine that would suit both of us? So I can go for a smoke break without him being angry for being left inside, or angry for being made to go back inside.

I am not allowed to put fencing/netting etc. on my balcony, so leaving it open for him is not an option. It is on the first floor, and he has already tried to jump onto and over the banister a few times. He has plenty of toys and a few cat trees inside.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe giving him a treat after getting in will soften the pain?

Comment: What exactly is forbidden for your apartment? Drilling holes to install hooks for a net or putting up any kind of net at all? I've seen several balconies where transparent nylon nets were installed using telescope rods that don't require any drilling and don't cause any damage to the building. My apartment came with a very simply DIY wooden frame that was just pressed into the opening of the balcony and is still held there by pressure alone.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming non-destructive approaches to attach netting are out of the question, here are some possible ideas to ease the tension.

**Make balcony breaks a dependable routine:**

Cats like routine and a clear schedule, having your smoke breaks always at the same times, and always the exact same number of breaks in a day will help the cat settle into a schedule, and reinforce the notion that balcony time is going to be available again later and doesn't need to be defended with claws.

**Take longer breaks:**

Since working from home sometimes comes with the benefit of more flexible hours, you could try taking longer breaks. Have a cup of your favorite beverage on the balcony after smoking, giving the cat a little extra time on the balcony while giving yourself some additional time to clear your head for work.

**Feeding time or jackpot treat after balcony breaks:**

Incorporate the balcony breaks into your feeding schedule, depending on your current feeding regimen you might feed smaller portions, but more frequently and always after a balcony break. Alternatively, offer a jackpot treat (something special that the cat is absolutely crazy about) after returning inside, and reserve this treat just for this occasion, reinforcing the notion that returning inside when asked is a good thing.

**Trade for something better:**

Outside time, even if it is just on a balcony, is a big deal for indoor cats. I would suggest trying to get the cat to accept a harness, and after the work day is done go for a short walk on a leash. This could help reduce the relative importance of balcony breaks in the mind of your cat, and help to ease the tension when it is time to leave the balcony because something even better is coming later.

Comment: As an alternative to feeding time, one could also offer a high-value treat at the end of balcony time, making the cat more excited to go inside and get that favorite snack.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be to build a fenced enclosure which rests *on* the deck, a feline playpen or "catio". That avoids the rule about not attaching netting to the deck itself, though the board may not be much happier about it.

Comment: You can purchase fully-netted pop-up cat playpens that might skirt the rules a bit more due to resembling one for children...